# Writing a formula with the given limits

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I'm stuck on a math question regarding creating possible formulas for a graph with limits. The question is as follows:

Sketch a graph of a rational function f that satisfies the following conditions:

I) $f(2) = 0$

II) $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}f(x) = 0$

III) $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = -\infty$

IV) $\lim_{x\to 3^-}f(x) = \infty$

V) $\lim_{x\to 3^+}f(x) = -\infty$

I really have no idea how to start. Could someone give some hints or point me to some reference material?

Comment: My answer to your question is about how to come up with a formula for such an $f$, which is what you say initially is your problem, but then the question you quote says you just need to sketch the graph. I'll leave my answer up in case you are interested in an explicit formula.

Comment: Already sketched a possible graph. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok so we need a rational function, which is the quotient of two polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.

We need $f(2)=0$ so we need a factor $x-2$ in $p$.

We need $f$ to get small when $x$ gets big, so we need the degree of $q$ to be greater than the degree of $p$.

Can you do the rest?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** try to find the horizontal and vertical asymptote with the limits that are given.